# Cannot invoke "java.util.List.iterator()" error

Tags: java, swing

I'm trying to create a GUI for my console application but I run into an error when trying to use the print button which I cannot understand why.

This is the Code

```
    package com.company;
import java.util.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.text.DateFormat;
import java.text.ParseException;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.List;
import javax.swing.*;

public class WestminsterSkinConsultationManagerGUI extends JFrame {
    private static WestminsterSkinConsultationManager manager;
    private final ArrayList<Doctor> doctors;
    private JTextField nameField;
    private JTextField surnameField;
    private JTextField dobField;
    private JTextField mobileField;
    private JTextField licenseField;
    private JTextField specializationField;
    private JTextField deleteField;
    private JButton addButton;
    private JButton deleteButton;
    private JButton printButton;
    private JButton saveButton;
    private JButton exitButton;
    private JTextArea doctorListArea;

    public WestminsterSkinConsultationManagerGUI() {
        // Initialize the manager
        manager = new WestminsterSkinConsultationManager();
        this.doctors = new ArrayList<Doctor>();


        // Set up the frame
        setTitle("Westminster Skin Consultation Manager");
        setSize(600, 400);
        setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        // Create the panel for the input fields
        JPanel inputPanel = new JPanel();
        inputPanel.setLayout(new GridLayout(7, 2));

        // Create the input fields
        nameField = new JTextField();
        surnameField = new JTextField();
        dobField = new JTextField();
        mobileField = new JTextField();
        licenseField = new JTextField();
        specializationField = new JTextField();
        deleteField = new JTextField();

        // Add the input fields to the panel
        inputPanel.add(new JLabel("Name:"));
        inputPanel.add(nameField);
        inputPanel.add(new JLabel("Surname:"));
        inputPanel.add(surnameField);
        inputPanel.add(new JLabel("Date of birth:"));
        inputPanel.add(dobField);
        inputPanel.add(new JLabel("Mobile number:"));
        inputPanel.add(mobileField);
        inputPanel.add(new JLabel("Medical license number:"));
        inputPanel.add(licenseField);
        inputPanel.add(new JLabel("Specialization:"));
        inputPanel.add(specializationField);
        inputPanel.add(new JLabel("Medical license number to delete:"));
        inputPanel.add(deleteField);

        // Create the panel for the buttons
        JPanel buttonPanel = new JPanel();
        buttonPanel.setLayout(new GridLayout(5, 1));

        // Create the buttons
        addButton = new JButton("Add Doctor");
        deleteButton = new JButton("Delete Doctor");
        printButton = new JButton("Print Doctors");
        saveButton = new JButton("Save to File");
        exitButton = new JButton("Exit");

        // Add the buttons to the panel
        buttonPanel.add(addButton);
        buttonPanel.add(deleteButton);
        buttonPanel.add(printButton);
        buttonPanel.add(saveButton);
        buttonPanel.add(exitButton);

        // Create the panel for the doctor list
        JPanel listPanel = new JPanel();
        doctorListArea = new JTextArea();
        doctorListArea.setEditable(false);
        JScrollPane scrollPane = new JScrollPane(doctorListArea);
        listPanel.add(scrollPane);

        // Add the input panel, button panel, and list panel to the frame
        add(inputPanel, BorderLayout.WEST);
        add(buttonPanel, BorderLayout.EAST);
        add(listPanel, BorderLayout.SOUTH);

        // Add action listeners to the buttons
        addButton.addActionListener(new AddButtonListener());
        deleteButton.addActionListener(new DeleteButtonListener());
        printButton.addActionListener(new PrintButtonListener());
        saveButton.addActionListener(new SaveButtonListener());
        exitButton.addActionListener(new ExitButtonListener());

        // Display the frame
        setVisible(true);
    }

    // Inner class for the Add button listener
    private class AddButtonListener implements ActionListener {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            // Get the input values
            String name = nameField.getText();
            String surname = surnameField.getText();
            String dobString = dobField.getText();
            String mobile = mobileField.getText();
            String license = licenseField.getText();
            String specialization = specializationField.getText();

            // Create a new doctor object with the input values
            DateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy");
            Date dob = null;
            try {
                dob = df.parse(dobString);
            } catch (ParseException ex) {
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Error: Invalid date of birth format. Use dd/MM/yyyy.");
                return;
            }
            Doctor doctor = new Doctor(name, surname, dob, mobile, license, specialization);

            // Add the doctor to the manager
            manager.addDoctor(doctor);
        }
    }

    // Inner class for the Delete button listener
    private class DeleteButtonListener implements ActionListener {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            // Get the medical license number to delete
            String license = deleteField.getText();

            // Delete the doctor with the specified medical license number
            manager.deleteDoctor(license);
        }
    }

    // Inner class for the Print button listener
    private class PrintButtonListener implements ActionListener {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            // Clear the text area
            doctorListArea.setText("");


                // Print the list of doctors
                List<Doctor> doctors = manager.getDoctors();
                for (Doctor doctor : doctors) {
                    doctorListArea.append("Name: " + doctor.getName() + "\n");
                    doctorListArea.append("Surname: " + doctor.getSurname() + "\n");
                    doctorListArea.append("Date of birth: " + doctor.getDateOfBirth() + "\n");
                    doctorListArea.append("Mobile number: " + doctor.getMobileNumber() + "\n");
                    doctorListArea.append("Medical license number: " + doctor.getMedicalLicenceNumber() + "\n");
                    doctorListArea.append("Specialization: " + doctor.getSpecialisation() + "\n\n");
                }
            }
        }

        // Inner class for the Save button listener
        private static class SaveButtonListener implements ActionListener {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                // Save the list of doctors to a file
                manager.saveToFile();
            }
        }

        // Inner class for the Exit button listener
        private static class ExitButtonListener implements ActionListener {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                // Close the program
                System.exit(0);
            }
        }

        public static void main(String[] args) {
            new WestminsterSkinConsultationManagerGUI();
        }
    }
```

This is the error I Get

> Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot invoke "java.util.List.iterator()" because "doctors" is null
> at com.company.WestminsterSkinConsultationManagerGUI$PrintButtonListener.actionPerformed(WestminsterSkinConsultationManagerGUI.java:158)
> at java.desktop/javax.swing.AbstractButton.fireActionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:1972)
> at java.desktop/javax.swing.AbstractButton$Handler.actionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:2313)
> at java.desktop/javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.fireActionPerformed(DefaultButtonModel.java:405)
> at java.desktop/javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.setPressed(DefaultButtonModel.java:262)
> at java.desktop/javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicButtonListener.mouseReleased(BasicButtonListener.java:279)
> at java.desktop/java.awt.Component.processMouseEvent(Component.java:6616)
> at java.desktop/javax.swing.JComponent.processMouseEvent(JComponent.java:3398)
> at java.desktop/java.awt.Component.processEvent(Component.java:6381)
> at java.desktop/java.awt.Container.processEvent(Container.java:2266)
> at java.desktop/java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Component.java:4991)
> at java.desktop/java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2324)
> at java.desktop/java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4823)
> at java.desktop/java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.retargetMouseEvent(Container.java:4948)
> at java.desktop/java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.processMouseEvent(Container.java:4575)
> at java.desktop/java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Container.java:4516)
> at java.desktop/java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2310)
> at java.desktop/java.awt.Window.dispatchEventImpl(Window.java:2780)
> at java.desktop/java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4823)
> at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:775)
> at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:720)
> at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:714)
> at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:399)
> at java.base/java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:86)
> at java.base/java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:97)
> at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue$5.run(EventQueue.java:747)
> at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue$5.run(EventQueue.java:745)
> at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:399)
> at java.base/java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:86)
> at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:744)
> at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:203)
> at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:124)
> at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:113)
> at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:109)
> at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:101)
> at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:90)

Comment: `doctors` is null at `for (Doctor doctor : doctors) {...`. You can avoid the exception by putting a null check before this. However, to ensure the desired functionality - check if the `manager` is initialized properly and is returning the values you are expecting here.

Answer (score 0):

The problem lies in your constructor.

You are creating the manager, but never instantiating the doctors list there.

```
public WestminsterSkinConsultationManagerGUI() {
        // Initialize the manager
        manager = new WestminsterSkinConsultationManager();
        this.doctors = new ArrayList<Doctor>();
```

instead of are instantiating the local `this.doctors` of your JFrame class `WestminsterSkinConsultationManagerGUI`.

And then, you are using the manager one on the loop:

```
List<Doctor> doctors = manager.getDoctors();
```

If the idea is the manager controlling the doctors list, remove the local one and change the constructor of `WestminsterSkinConsultationManagerGUI`:

```
public WestminsterSkinConsultationManagerGUI() {
        // Initialize the manager
        manager = new WestminsterSkinConsultationManager();
        ...
}
```

and internally on `WestminsterSkinConsultationManager` it creates the doctors list, like:

```
public WestminsterSkinConsultationManager() {
  this.doctors = new ArrayList<Doctor>();
}
```

This will avoid the doctors issue of being null.
Also, remove the local doctors of your JFrame class to avoid this confusion =)